# How to enable lazy loading of to-many-relationship objects' properties?

Tags: ios, core-data, lazy-loading, one-to-many

I have a Post object that next to other properties contains a boolean "hidden" and a possibly very long string "content". There is a Feed model that has a one-to-many-relationship (inverse) to Post objects.

When I query a Feed for its contained Post objects and then only access the "hidden" property on each fetched Post object I can see from the debug logging of Core Data that it fetches the whole Post object's properties. That means that also the "content" string (often 3000+ characters) are fetched from the SQLite database. I found that this slows down the fetching of all the Post objects a lot.

How can I make the Post objects accesses to lazy-load their properties, meaning that when I query the fetched Post objects for the "hidden" value than no other parameters get fetched.

I might add that I use MagicalRecord to access Core Data.

I hope there is another way to this than using the "propertiesToFetch" method on manual NSFetchRequest instances.

Answer (score 0):

Did you read [Faulting and Uniquing](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdFaultingUniquing.html) in the Core Data Programming Guide?
Look particularly into ["Turning Objects Into Faults"](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdFaultingUniquing.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001202-SW2).

> You can turn a realized object into a fault with the `refreshObject:mergeChanges:` method.

If memory is not the issue, but just performance you should resort to the `NSDictionaryRepresentation` type and just retrieve the properties you need.

Comment: Actually the main problem I see is not the memory consumption after the Post objects were fetched, but rather that all properties of a Post object are fetched from the data store, where I only requested the "hidden" property. This leads to long fetch durations for each object, as all the other properties' values are read from the datastore unnecessarily.

Comment: OK, then I suppose you have to go with the `NSDictionaryRepresentation` and specify your property with `propertiesToFetch`. Also - if you just want to exclude the hidden once, use a predicate.